# What kind of ID Number, if any, did the Soviets institute for all their citizens?

Tags: soviet-union, government

In the United States, every citizen has a social security number for income purposes. **It's a 9-digit number.** This began in 1935, though I was surprised to learn from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number#History) that until 1986, most people only got their number around the age of 14. Today, everyone gets it at birth.

Did the Soviets also give **everyone** a ID number? Was it a 9-digit number? 10-digit? A 7-character alphanumeric sequence?

I searched for this on wikipedia's [Passport System in the Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passport_system_in_the_Soviet_Union), because I know they used internal passports. I looked at both the English and Russian versions of the article, but could not find examples of ID numbers.

I did of course also google images and found this:

[image]

The first entry appears to be a birth date because I see the number "1946". There is a printed number, "I-T3 No. 681711". However, a 6-digit number can have at most 10^6 = 1 million unique entries. The USSR around the time of the war had 170 million people, and around 1990, around 290 million people. So a 6-digit number is nowhere near enough to hold that many unique ID numbers. You would need a minimum of a 9-digit number.

This makes me think the internal passports were not issued to everyone, only certain people of whom there could only be a million or less. But then, the "I-T3" could be part of it?

(**Edit:** It's actually I-TЭ, where Э is the 30th letter in the Russian Alphabet. TЭ is a district code. The I is a roman numeral but as of yet I don't know what it really means.)

Is there some ID document given to everyone, that gives you a unique ID number? I looked at birth certificates too but came up emtpy.

Comment: 1946 is the date of issue. The birth date is 1913.

Comment: I don't know the Soviet system, but in the Eastern block people generally got an ID# at birth and a passport like ID book around 14. De centralizing the id of citizens was a big deal in late 80-90s in places like Hungary.

Comment: @fdb no, 1946 is the date until which the passport is valid. It is issued in 1941.

Comment: @Anixx. But I got the birth date right, I think?

Comment: @fdb yes........

Comment: There's a reason for that. **The Social Security number was not supposed to be an identification.** It was simply a record locator for your social security benefits, which your employer pays into as you work, and then get you paid out of after you retire. Children didn't need one because children didn't work as employees.

Comment: @T.E.D. That may well be, but a 9-digit num can hold 1 billion values, obviously plenty for the USA's population back then and even today. Therefore I think it was still intended for "everyone", even if you didn't get assigned until you started working. (BTW, not-so-fun fact: there was a lot of child labor in USA back in early 1900's, tho not sure about 1930's.) I only mentioned this to contrast it with Soviet internal passports, which apparently were **not** intended for "everyone", just country peasants. That's why I looked into birth certificates but did not find it there either.

Comment: @DrZ214 - There was a lot of slop in the numbering system. For example, the first three digits were reserved for the state of issuance. The second two are a group of issuance number, and only the last four specify uniqueness in that group. This way someone who knows what they are doing can gather some info about you just by looking at the number (eg: what state you lived in when you got it, and roughly how old you are likely to be), and often times can spot a fake number. The latter issue is why illegal immigrants typically use someone else's number rather than make one up.

Comment: @DrZ214 - There's honestly enough (and interesting enough) to write about the history of US SSN's that I would have liked to write it in an answer, but it wouldn't really be answering this question.

Comment: Don't forget that till the 1960's the rural population was not even isssued internal passports (without which one could not permanently reside in a town of any size), being effectively serfs of their local kolkhoz. I doubt anyone bothered to issue them global id numbers, as opposed to local records.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg after the revolution of 1917 the internal passports were abolished because they were viewed as a factor LIMITING movement and oppressive. They were slowly re-introduced since 1930s, starting from city population but existence of a passport was never a factor in the right to travel. You are repeating propaganda.

Comment: @Anixx *I* am repeating propaganda. Now, that's a good one.

Comment: @Greg and it was quite the opposite in the Soviet bloc proper, eg we only had passports until independence of Latvia, when a unique personal code was introduced.

Comment: As far as I know there weren't any ID numbers. Definitely not during my childhood (1980ies). As for your passport it has the following fields and values: 1. Name, Father's name, surname: Elena Petrovna (Peter's daughter) Zenkevich (note that the name is written in different order from  the one required. 2.time and place of birth, place being Vilnius. 3.nationality: Polish 4.signature, 5.social status: [that of] individual worker, 6.relation to military service (blank) 7. Issuer: 5th dept of Militia of Vilnius city

Comment: 8. On what grounds is passport issued: seems to be birth entry of church (metr. from metrika) +some more info. Date of issue : 1941, 1 year after Soviet occupation of Lithuania

Answer (score 9):

The passport number included two parts, the series number and its proper number. This would allow for enough unique numbers. The passport number though would be changed if passport is re-issued or lost.

The unique identification of a person in the USSR was their name, date and place of birth.

People also had their birth certificate, which was numbered, but again, the number would change if it is lost.

There was no taxpayer number in the USSR, contrary to the answer by Danila Smirnov.

Answer (score 4):

"I-ТЭ № 681711" includes also the issue series ID - the "I-TЭ" part (which in this case consists of a roman numeral from I to XXXIII and the issue region code (two cyrillic letters), by the way, so it is not "I-T3"). This way, while a single series can't have more than 1 million passports, you can have multiple series, which gives us 33 million passports per region (in 1939 USSR consisted of 138 regions). This ID number is unique only to the document, not to its holder! When the passport is reissued, one is required to register the new ID with all relevant institutions.

Comment: There was no ИНН in the USSR. It is issued to people since 1999, to firms since 1993.

Comment: @Anixx Indeed, I guess I was confused by ИННs issued for Soviet passport holders in the 90s. Deleted that part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize it could have been a "Z" or "Э". Can you explain what the roman numeral I to XXXIII is for?

Comment: @DrZ214 I think it was simply for obfuscation, to prevent forgery. Series number was pretty fluid, even region codes changed often (and often there were several codes simultaneously assigned to one region, especially to the ones with large population) - for example, in Moscow during 1979 were issued passports with series XXII-МЮ, and during 1988 - I-СБ, so it could be easily checked if passports of a series were issued during a given period at a given location.

Comment: @DrZ214 It is Э